# django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for '' not found. '' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I am trying to create a url-shohrtener and it gives me this error:

> django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for '' not found. '' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('shorturl.urls')),
]
```

here is my apps urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('<str:id>/', views.redirect_url, name='redirect'),
]
```

these are the views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import Url
import random
import string

def redirect_url(request, id):
    urls = Url.objects.filter(short=id)
    link = ""
    for i in urls:
        link = i.url
    return redirect(link)

def index(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        link = request.POST.get("link")
        short = ""
        if Url.objects.filter(url=link).exists():
            urls = Url.objects.all()
            for i in urls:
                if i.url == link:
                    short = i.short
                    break
        else:    
            short = get_short_code()
            url = Url(url=link, short=short)
            url.save()
        new_url = request.get_host() + "/" + short
        return render(request, 'shorturl/index.html', {"new_url":new_url})

    return render(request, 'shorturl/index.html')

def get_short_code():
    length = 6
    char = string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits + string.ascii_lowercase
    while True:
        short_id = ''.join(random.choice(char) for x in range(length))
        if Url.objects.filter(short=short_id).exists():
            continue
        else:
            return short_id
```

just in case it is important this is the template:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Shroten URL</title>
    <script>
      function myFunction() {
        /* Get the text field */
        var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput");

        /* Select the text field */
        copyText.select();
        copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999); /* For mobile devices */

        /* Copy the text inside the text field */
        document.execCommand("copy");
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="container" style="padding-top: 5%;">
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Link</label>
            <input name="link" type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Shorten</button>
        </form>
        {% if new_url %}
          <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Short Link</label>
            <input name="link" type="text" value= {{new_url}} class="form-control" id="myInput" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
          </div>
          <button onclick="myFunction()" class="btn btn-primary">COPY</button>
          
        {% endif %}
    </div>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
    <!--
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.5.4/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-q2kxQ16AaE6UbzuKqyBE9/u/KzioAlnx2maXQHiDX9d4/zp8Ok3f+M7DPm+Ib6IU" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-pQQkAEnwaBkjpqZ8RU1fF1AKtTcHJwFl3pblpTlHXybJjHpMYo79HY3hIi4NKxyj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

The error I'm getting just on the terminal the website works fine.
The whole error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File
"C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\new\xp\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py",
line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)   File "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\new\xp\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py",
line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)   File "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\new\xp\Url-shortener\shorturl\views.py", line
12, in redirect_url
    return redirect(link)   File "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\new\xp\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py",
line 41, in redirect
    return redirect_class(resolve_url(to, *args, **kwargs))   File "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\new\xp\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py",
line 131, in resolve_url
    return reverse(to, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)   File "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\new\xp\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py",
line 87, in reverse
    return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))   File "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\new\xp\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py",
line 685, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg) django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for '' not found. '' is not a valid view function or pattern
name.
```

Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: `urls = Url.objects.filter(short=id)` shouldn't this be `urls = Url.objects.get(short=id)`? i.e. short should be unique. Likely no such instance exists for the value of short passed. Use `get_object_or_404(Url, short=id)` instead. Which will simply give a 404 if no such instance of the model exists.

Comment: we can do it in both ways .filter() gives a queryset so I used a for loop to take the short variable

Comment: `.filter()` gives a queryset true, but in your use case `short` is meant to be unique and you want only one result. Why loop for no reason when you can simply get the result you want? (Also put `unique=True` if you haven't on the field short in your model) Also the benefit of using `.get()` is that it assumes exactly one result would be present. If you get multiple or none it throws an exception. While of course filter has no issues with that.

Comment: Thanks I would change it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the urls.py instead of `path('<str:id>/', views.redirect_url, name='redirect')` use something like `path('l/<str:id>/', views.redirect_url, name='redirect')` because the null value is passed in the place of id which triggers the redirect_url function besides the index function when you visit the website. passing something like /l/ in the url pattern solves the issue.